# display: list-item not working properly in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, rendering, listitem

I'm pretty sure it's documented somewhere, but my Googling and looking at the mdn didn't give me anything substantial to go on.

Consider the following example:

```
<doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Array test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <style scoped>
      div {
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
        display: list-item;
        list-style-type: decimal;
      }
    </style>

    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

If you render it in Chrome or safari, or any webkit browser I could get my hands on the div will be numbered 1, 2, 3, 4. But in Firefox all items will be 0.

Is there a way around this? In pure CSS?

TIA

Comment: Probably not relevant to your problem, but `<doctype html>` is not a valid doctype. You're missing the `!` in `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a pure CSS solution, you could explicitly use a CSS counter, right?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279635/xml-counting-elements-in-a-list-does-not-work-in-firefox-can-someone-help) and a [site](http://www.richinstyle.com/bugs/mozillademo.html) (Section L) that note this to be (has been) a bug in Firefox.

The only solution I have found is that the `div` items must be wrapped by an `ol`: http://jsfiddle.net/Rvux3/3/, which, of course, is not a pure CSS solution, nor would it validate (you might as well use `li` items if you are going to have the `ol`).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I can't touch the HTML, but css counter it is!